# How can I increase select query on table with 60gb

Tags: sql-server, sql-optimization, sqlgeography

I have a table with about 60gb and with these columns:

```
ColumnA: type: Int
ColumnB: type: Int
ColumnC: type: Real
ColumnD: type: Real
ColumnE: type: Real
ColumnF: type: Real
ColumnG: type: Real
```

I have an `index [ColunaA, ColunaB]`

I have a laptop with `16gb` of `ram`, `windows 10 pro`, `sql server 2017 enterprise`, `SSD` with `1gb read / write`.

You can query this table like this:

```
Select TOP 250000 * from table
where columnA> @parameter AND columnA <@ parameter2
AND columnB> @ parameter3 AND columnB <@ parameter4
```

without taking minutes / hours to develop a result?

Should I use partitioned tables with filegroups stored on other SSD disks to increase query performance?

Comment: Proper index would help `CREATE INDEX my_idx ON my_tab_name(columnA, ColumnB)`; Assuming that your where conditions are SARGable.

Comment: I already have that index. that's not enough

Comment: Then standard procedure: please post query execution plan(I guess that you have some issue with FULL-SCAN) Also for your own sake avoid Real data type.

Comment: Any reason to avoid real data type? I want to reduce storage of data and I think that real type is better for it. But I dont know if it is worst for performace..